# Prawn-table: Iterating Through Active Record Relation Object to fill in Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, prawn

I am using the ruby gem: [prawn](https://rubygems.org/gems/prawn) and the extension [prawn-table](https://rubygems.org/gems/prawn-table) to provide prawn the functionality of creating tables.

The basics of creating a table with prawn [displayed here](http://prawnpdf.org/prawn-table-manual.pdf) is straight forward when you have static data:

```
# This works.  Easy because it is static data
def prepare_for_print
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new
  pdf.font_size 11
  pdf.font "Times-Roman"

  pdf.table([ ["short", "short", "loooooooooooooooooooong "*30],
              ["short", "loooooooooooooooooooong "*15, "short"],
              ["loooooooooooooooooooong "*10, "short", "short"] ])
  return pdf
end
```

Great.  That wasn't bad.  But now I want to iterate through an active record relation object, but my attempt is just not working:

```
def prepare_for_print
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new
  pdf.font_size 11
  pdf.font "Times-Roman"


  calls_by_disability.each do |disability|
    pdf.text "#{disability}", style: :bold, color: "001133"
    pdf.table([ ["Call ID", "Date", "County", "Service Category", "Service", "Notes"],
              disability.calls.each do |call|
                ["hello", "world", "foo", "bar", "bazz", "adsfsa"],
              end
              ])
  end
  return pdf
end
```

The issue is with iterating through the associated calls:

```
disability.calls.each do |call|
  ["hello", "world", "foo", "bar", "bazz", "adsfsa"],
end
```

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  calls_by_disability.each do |disability|
    pdf.text "#{disability}", style: :bold, color: "001133"

    header = ["Call ID", "Date", "County", "Service Category", "Service", "Notes"]
    table_data = []
    table_data << header
    disability.calls.map do |call|
      table_data << [call.id, call.date, call.country, call.service_category, call_service, call.notes]
    end
    pdf.table(table_data)
  end
```

Comment: With your suggested answer, I am getting this error: `data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects`

Comment: what about the edit? I can't test it, I am only trying to help because I have spent few hours with prawn-table today at work and it's pain in the ** :) Please see the edit and try to follow the error, they are pretty descriptive.

Comment: I think I'm really close thanks to your help.  The issue is that `table_data` has an extra `[ ]` wrapping the data for some reason for each call.  I tried taking `map` out and replacing it with `.each` but that didn't do it.

Comment: give me 10 mins, I have to finish something and edit the answer

Comment: cool thanks!  It is still giving me this error: `data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects`